# Coloring triangles in a Delaunay triangulation on the surface of a 3d sphere.

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, coloring, triangulation

Suppose a delaunay triangulation over the surface of a 3d sphere (or generally some 3d surface of something topologically equivalent to the sphere). How many colors do I need to color its triangles so that triangles sharing an edge have different colors?

My idea: For the delaunay triangulation of a set of points on the plane, 3 colors are always enough.

Proof: taking the 1-ring (all the triangles that touch an epsilon small circle around a vertex) 3 colors are always enough to color it.

[image]

This is taken from wikipedia. The 4rth point from the bottom, (4rth in the sense of y coordinate) has a 1-ring of size 5, thus I need three colors to color it.

I think the argument still holds for the surface of a sphere. Am I correct?

Will it still hold even if there is genus?

Comment: The small-ring argument would work for general maps, won't it? Even for a tertrahedron ...

Comment: I think yes. Even genus seems irrelevant. Seems a little suspicious, that is why I asked

Comment: The point being if it works for a tetrahedron, it must be wrong. You need four colors to color a tetrahedron.